Simpler example of unbounded function $f\in H^{\frac n 2}(\mathbb R^n)$
We know $\|u\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)} \le C\|u\|_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ for $u \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $s > \frac n2$ from Sobolev Imbedding Theorem, then it's natural to think the case of $s=\frac n2$:

Give an example of unbounded function $f\in H^{\frac n 2}(\mathbb R^n)$.

I know there is an example here but it isn't easy to verify it. And also, I know an example for $n=2$:
$$f(x)=\left(\log \frac1{|x|}\right)^\alpha,\quad \alpha\in\left(0,\frac12\right)$$
So can we generalize it to the $n$ dimension?
If you have other ideas for constructing functions which are easy to verify, I would also be very grateful.
